# Sort multiple arrays from highest to lowest

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I'm displaying data from multiple `JSON` files using an `array` and using `sort();` to sort the values of `ID` from highest to lowest.

The problem I'm facing is that `sort();` is ordering both arrays separately, causing the following will be outputted:

- 11
- 9
- 7
- 56
- 12
- 5

11, 9 and 7 *(the first array*) are sorted and 56, 12 and 5 *(the second array)* are sorted. How do I merge the arrays so that the following is outputted:

- 56
- 12
- 11
- 9
- 7
- 5

Here's my JSON array:

```
$homepage = array();
$homepage[] = '{
  "info": {
    "collection": [
      {
        "ID": "7"
      },
      {
        "ID": "9"
      },
      {
        "ID": "11"
      }
    ]
  }
}';
$homepage[] = '{
  "info": {
    "collection": [
      {
        "ID": "12"
      },
      {
        "ID": "56"
      },
      {
        "ID": "5"
      }
    ]
  }
}';
```

Here's where I decode the JSON array, sort it and echo it:

```
foreach ($homepage as $homepage2) {
$data = json_decode($homepage2, false);

usort($data->info->collection, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b->ID - $a->ID;
});

foreach($data->info->collection as $key) {
    echo'
    '.$key->ID.'
    ';
}
}
```

Comment: too long to answer in comments... answering as answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to decode those jsons to arrays and add them to for example `$homepage_decoded`...

```
$homepage_decoded = array();
foreach($homepage as $hp)
   $homepage_decoded[] = json_decode($hp,true);

$merged = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $merged));
```

And then sort `$merged`...

```
sort($merged,SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Excuse me if there is some syntax error in code I given, writting it from phone. But idea should be clear.